# Problems with Ionic in android 6 and IOS 9

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, cross-platform, ionic-view

I have a cross-platform Ionic application,
I have some problems in ionic view application view which is running correctly for APK version

frist problem: I'm using socket.io to check user internet connection it fails all the time on IOS 9, although it's running fine on ionic view version for android 6 and APK version

second problem: icons is not clickable on android 6 and IOS 9, although it's on APK version

```
<i class="icon ion-ios-download-outline"
                       external-link="result.file.uri"></i>
```

`external-link` is a directive redirect to the link on the click
and it's working for APK version
any help ?

** edit

externalLink directive code

```
angular.module('ivf.directives').directive('externalLink', ExternalLinkDirective);

function ExternalLinkDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.click(function ($event) {
                if ($event.isDefaultPrevented()) return;

                var link = $scope.$eval($attrs['externalLink']);
                if (link) {
                    window.open(link, '_system');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: Please show the externalLink directive code

Answer (score 1):

1st

To check the internet connection, you could use [Cordova Plugin Network Information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information).

[Example from documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information#quick-example):

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

2nd

Which icons are you talking about? Please show your code